# Cannot return method using module exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-models

I am trying to make a `database` file that **delivers connectio**n, model etc for `mongoose (MongoDb)`.

> So when I return the Mongoose Model, the create method becomes
>   "undefined".

**`database.js`**

```
//model connection 
exports.MongoModel = async function ({connectionName, collection, schema}){
    //get connection data 
    const databaseData = connectionsArray[connectionName];

    //create url 
    const mongoUrl = `${dbUrl}${databaseData.databaseName}`;

    //connection 
    const connection = Mongoose.createConnection(mongoUrl, databaseData.options);

    //model with schema
    const Model = connection.model('files',schema);

    console.log(Model.create);// displays [Function: create] in console

    //return model
    return Model
}//MongoModel ends
```

When imported to the other file

**`FileUploads.js`**

```
const { MongoModel } = require('@src/config/database');


const FilesModel = MongoModel({connectionName:'files', collection: 'files', schema: FilesSchema});

console.log(FilesModel); // Displays Promise { Model { files } }
console.log(FilesModel.create); // Displays undefined
```

*Note: I am very new to this platform so please pardon me typo's.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code 'MongoModel' references an [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function which always returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). That is why you see `Promise { Model { files } }` when you log the object to your console. Two things you can do are:

Option 1: Remove the 'async' key word from your function declaration. This way your function returns your model object instead of a promise.
Option 2: Add a callback to get the data returned by the promise as shown below:

```
MongoModel({connectionName:'files', collection: 'files', schema: FilesSchema})
    .then((FileModel) => {
         console.log(FileModel.create); // should display [Function: create]
});
```

Comment: Going from an async function to a callback-based one doesn't sound like a good move.

Comment: I wasn't recommending a particular approach. I was just making him aware of two options he could take to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks, @IyanuAdelekan for the answer. I have remove async as it was not necessary for the method.

Answer (score 0):

Well try it like this:

```
//model connection 
function MongoModel({connectionName, collection, schema}){
    //get connection data 
    const databaseData = connectionsArray[connectionName];

    //create url 
    const mongoUrl = `${dbUrl}${databaseData.databaseName}`;

    //connection 
    const connection = Mongoose.createConnection(mongoUrl, databaseData.options);

    //model with schema
    const Model = connection.model('files',schema);

    console.log(Model.create);// displays [Function: create] in console

    //return model
    return Model
}//MongoModel ends 

module.exports = { MongoModel }
```

You need to export an Object with your `MongoModel` in it. Now you should be able to destructure it at the import statement.

And i dont see a reason to use `async` here